# Change size of my zoom container with elevatezoom

Tags: jquery, zooming

I am trying to use this plugin : http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

I chose the third exemple: Gallery & Lightbox.

Is there a way, in their css/javascript to alter css propeties so that for exemple I put the zoom in fullscreen mode.
*
The plugin generate a container:

```
<div class="zoomContainer" style="-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 8px; height: 274px; width: 411px;"></div>
```

I would like to alter this and put my sizes (height, width...)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#image").elevateZoom( {  gallery:'image-additional-carousel', 
                            galleryActiveClass: 'active',
                            zoomWindowHeight:600,
                            zoomWindowWidth:600,
                       } );
```

with zoomWindowHeight / zoomWindowWidth u can set the height , width of the container